# If I delete my answer, how many reputation is required to someone to still view it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, deleted-answers

I have read on somewhere SO that deleted answers are viewable for users with high reputation.

```
Q1: How many reputation is required to view deleted answers of others?
Q2: Can someone still downvote on deleted answers?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 10,000 Reputation
2. You can't vote up or down on deleted answers, and when rep is recalculated, votes from deleted items aren't taken into account (unless it was deleted *because* it was flagged, e.g. offensive).

   - Check out https://stackoverflow.com/reputation while logged in to see what your rep *should* be :)

You can check out the [FAQ entry on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) for any other questions.